# How to solve the equation having multiple variables?

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, non-convex-optimization

I have the following set of equations:

$A_{1} = M_{1}*B_{11} + M_{2}*B_{12}~~~~~~~~~~~~......~~Eqn.(1)\\
A_{2} = M_{1}*B_{21} + M_{2}*B_{22}~~~~~~~~~~~~......~~Eqn.(2)\\
:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:\\
A_{n} = M_{1}*B_{n1} + M_{2}*B_{n2}~~~~~~~~~~~......~~Eqn.(n)$

where $A_{1}$ to $A_{n}$ and $(B_{11}, B_{12})$ to $(B_{n1}, B_{n2})$ are the known values all belonging to $\mathbb{R}$. Also, $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are the multivariate equations as shown below:

$M_{1} = (X_{9} X_{5} X_{1}) + (X_{9} X_{6} X_{3}) + (X_{10} X_{7} X_{1}) + (X_{10} X_{8} X_{3})$, and
$M_{2} = (X_{9} X_{5} X_{2}) + (X_{9} X_{6} X_{4}) + (X_{10} X_{7} X_{2}) + (X_{10} X_{8} X_{4})$

Here, $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}, X_{5}, X_{6}, X_{7}, X_{8}, X_{9}$ and $X_{10}$ are the variables in $\mathbb{R}$. We can also represent these equations in the matrix form as shown below:

$M_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}X_{9} & X_{10}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_{5} & X_{6}\\X_{7} & X_{8}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_{1} \\ X_{3}\end{bmatrix}\\
M_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}X_{9} & X_{10}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_{5} & X_{6}\\X_{7} & X_{8}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_{2} \\ X_{4}\end{bmatrix}$

Now, I can get the values of $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ by solving the linear equations $Eqn. (1)$ to $Eqn. (n)$ shown above. Let's say, after solving those equations, I get the value of $M_{1} = K_{1}$ and the value of $M_{2} = K_{2}$, where $K_{1}, K_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, now we can write as follows:

$K_{1} = (X_{9} X_{5} X_{1}) + (X_{9} X_{6} X_{3}) + (X_{10} X_{7} X_{1}) + (X_{10} X_{8} X_{3})$, and
$K_{2} = (X_{9} X_{5} X_{2}) + (X_{9} X_{6} X_{4}) + (X_{10} X_{7} X_{2}) + (X_{10} X_{8} X_{4})$

Now, my question is that what do we exactly call these above type of equations and how do we get the values of the variables $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}, X_{5}, X_{6}, X_{7}, X_{8}, X_{9}$ and $X_{10}$ by solving these equations.

What do I think is that there are no unique values for these variables, but we can get a solution set out of many existing ones. If I am right, we may take help of non-convex optimization methods. But, as I am new to this domain I don't know methods to solve these type of problems.

Thus, I request the answer to this question from the community.

Comment: Can't you simply put $(X_9,X_{10})=(K_1,K_2)$ and $\pmatrix{X_5&X_6\\ X_7&X_8}=\pmatrix{X_1&X_2\\ X_3&X_4}=I_2$?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this makes the answer biased. In another way, we consider only one possible set of solution. But in my case, the solution must not be limited to only one possible solution set. That's the reason why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to solve
$$
\underbrace{(K_1,K_2)}_{v^T}=\underbrace{(X_9,X_{10})}_{z^T}
\underbrace{\pmatrix{X_5&X_6\\ X_7&X_8}}_{X}
\underbrace{\pmatrix{X_1&X_2\\ X_3&X_4}}_{Y},
$$
or in a more abstract form, $v^T=z^TXY$, where the $z$ and the matrices $X,Y$ on the RHS are unknown. This should be easy. When $v\ne0$, there are three (possibly overlapping) classes of solutions according to the ranks of $X$ and $Y$:

- $X$ and $Y$ are any two invertible matrices and $z^T = v^TX^{-1}Y^{-1}$;
- $Y$ is any invertible matrix, $X=xv^TY^{-1}$ for some vector $x\ne0$ and $z$ is any vector such that $z^Tx=1$;
- $Y=yv^T$ for some vector $y\ne0$, $X$ is any invertible matrix and $z$ is any vector such that $z^TXy=1$.

When $v$ is known to be zero, the above three classes of solutions are still valid and there is one additional class of solutions:

- $Y=y_1y_2^T$ for some vectors $y_1$ and $y_2$, $X$ is any matrix and $z$ is any vector such that $(z^TXy_1)y_2^T=0$ (so, if $y_2\ne0$, we need $z\perp Xy_1$, otherwise $z$ is arbitrary).